# Scraping data from an interactive webmap

Tags: web-mapping, web-service

I'm to export all of the parcel data of a specific region (the website is in Mongolian, one needs to choose "Хөвсгөл" from "Аймаг/Хот" and "Ханх" from "Сум/Дүүрэг" from the top-left of the webpage) from the following website:

https://egazar.gov.mn/map?code=06746#!
[image]

I was able to determine from Inspect >> Network in my browser that the parcel features on screen are in JSON format, with a "geoserver.egazar.gov.mn" back-end. Clicking on each feature will show its properties on the webpage, and the following "WMS service" element appears in the Network panel:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"geo_view_parcel_soum.fid--594e8f7c_17abdd85d6a_5a97","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[1.120353000804684E7,6713930.22818748],[1.120346777720269E7,6713968.67643879],[1.120343553114264E7,6713978.08160285],[1.120343294365408E7,6713983.7786929],[1.120343913020867E7,6713996.42790132],[1.120343220901752E7,6713998.77323162],[1.120344211913055E7,6714034.61179007],[1.120346544572143E7,6714060.77555329],[1.120348946144284E7,6714067.04356585],[1.120351098861732E7,6714064.79411021],[1.120352119785828E7,6714071.91177896],[1.120362399263607E7,6714000.9503164],[1.120361725662559E7,6713987.92589275],[1.120359506559879E7,6713978.296648],[1.120359643887989E7,6713963.38749197],[1.120359138967816E7,6713956.10554074],[1.120357632377088E7,6713953.87717878],[1.120357263286919E7,6713946.70138464],[1.12035572057437E7,6713956.78523309],[1.120353000804684E7,6713930.22818748]]]},"geometry_name":"geometry","properties":{"parcel_id":"6707000426","old_parcel_id":"6707000426","valid_from":"2012-04-18Z","valid_till":"292278994-08-16Z","landuse":2205,"area_m2":6459,"address_khashaa":"1-03","address_streetname":"Хирвэс ","address_neighbourhood":null,"fill_color":"#455473","boundary_color":"#828282","boundary_width":1,"description":"Гэр, орон сууцны хашааны газар","description2":"Гэр, орон сууцны хашааны газар","au2":"06746"}}],"totalFeatures":"unknown","numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2021-07-19T08:18:38.052Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}}}
```

I need to extract all of the parcel data within the region's boundaries, preferably to CSV or a shapefile. How can I achieve this without going over them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

If you paste `http://geoserver.egazar.gov.mn/geoserver/wfs?request=getcapabilities&service=wfs` into QGIS' WFS connection box, you will be able to add any of the layers you need to a map and export them in any supported format.

Comment: You should probably note that web scraping can be a TOS violation.

Comment: Right, I should've mentioned that the web page requires third-party authentication for viewing the data and a direct authentication with the GeoServer to actually access them through WFS.

But there should be a way to scrape the data from each feature, since they're viewable in that "view-only" privilege, through the browser console, right?

Comment: If they meant you to fetch the data then they would have given wfs access - try contacting them to ask for the data

Comment: @emil did you ever manage to scrape the data?

Comment: @Werner - did you try the WFS endpoint?